# Uniform initialization syntax difference

Tags: c++, c++11, most-vexing-parse

What's the difference between doing

```
A a{ A() };
```

and,

```
A a( A{} );
```

to avoid the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)? When should I use a particular one?

Comment: In this particular situation, the simplest option would be `A a;`, right? If I don't misunderstand this, the syntax you suggest makes only sense when the temporary you want to pass to the constructor of `A` is of a different type than `A`, correct? I.e. `A a { B() };`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two syntaxes are equivalent in most situations, and which one to choose is mostly a matter of taste. If you are into uniform initialization, I would suggest doing:

```
A a{ A{} };
```

Otherwise, parentheses alone can be used to disambiguate:

```
A a((A())); // This can't be parsed as a function declaration
```

Notice, that there is one situation (very unlikely, I must say) where the two forms shown in your question are not equivalent. If your class `A` has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list<A>`, that constructor will be favored over the copy constructor when the braces are used:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() { }
    A(std::initializer_list<A> l) { std::cout << "init-list" << std::endl; }
    A(A const& a) { std::cout << "copy-ctor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(A{}); // Prints "copy-ctor" (or nothing, if copy elision is performed)
    A b{A()}; // Prints "init-list"
}
```

The above difference is shown in this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0c9fa59c1b5456ed1bf8ac1bd39cfa26-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

Comment: Actually, the first *doesn't* print "copy-ctor" for me. I think its copy-elision.

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Huh, right, the compiler is eliding the copy - but conceptually, the copy constructor is picked

Comment: Does copy-elision only happen when optimizations are enabled?

Comment: @MemyselfandI: No. On many compilers it will always be enabled unless you specifically disable it.

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Not necessarily. Copy elision happens completely at your compiler's discretion, but it is *more likely* to happen when optimizations are enabled

Comment: @MemyselfandI: With GCC and Clang, you can force the compiler to inhibit copy elision by passing the flag `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: Be warned that `-fno-elide-constructors` is [currently broken](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12208) on clang.

Answer (score 9):

In most situations they are equivalent, but `A a{ A() };` will prefer a `std::initializer_list` constructor if one is present, while `A a( A{} );` will prefer a move/copy constructor.

When the construct ends up calling a move/copy constructor, the construction of the new object can be elided, but this is not possible for a `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Neither syntax will ever be parsed as a function declaration, so both avoid the most-vexing-parse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
    A(A&&) {
        std::cout << "A(A&&)\n";
    }
    A(std::initializer_list<A>) {
        std::cout << "A(std::initializer_list<A>)\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    {A a{ A() };} // Prints "A()\n" "A(std::initializer_list<A>)\n"
    {A a( A{} );} // Prints "A()\n" and *possibly*
                  // (depending on copy elision) "A(A&&)\n"
}
```